# How to edit Mat Ripples properties in Mat Chip Angular

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, angular-material-6

I'm working on an angular app that uses mat chips in a data table. However, the data from the table is stored in a database and is retrieved via HTTP calls. So when I click on the delete button, the ripple extends until the table refreshes and it can grow really big.

Is there a way of modifying the ripple radius for mat chips or other Angular Material elements? I know I can disable it but modifying the radius would be the best.

Comment: I'm curious as to the cause of your ripple extending too large. If you're able to, create a stackblitz with a reproduction so we can find a root cause.

Comment: I'm waiting for the backend to answer before doing any kind of modifications. Even if it is on localHost it can take 0.2-0.3 seconds and during this time the ripple expands accordingly. I tried putting a timer on the backend to only return after 2 seconds and it will grow for about 1.5 seconds then settle at a max size then stay that way until we refresh the table

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure when it was introduced, but as of Material version 6.4.7 the [Ripples module](https://material.angular.io/components/ripple/overview) was added for more granular control of how ripples behave, allowing for defining the ripple radius, color, and more. Using this new module, you should be able to disable the native ripple effect on each component and override with your own:

```
<mat-chip disableRipple matRipple matRippleRadius="10">One fish</mat-chip>
```

If you don't disable the component's native ripple, each click will produce two ripples.

Comment: Thanks, its works but acts weird. I disabled the ripple in the mat -chip and tried to add it on the mat-icon for the delete inside. However, when I click on the icon the ripple appears at the other extreme end of the chip if the property matRippleCentered is true.